# Computing inverse Fourier transform of a step function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I am trying to compute the inverse Fourier transform of this function: $F(x)=\chi_{[-1,1]\times[-1,1]}$.

Using the definition of inverse Fourier transform,

$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(F) \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi} \chi_{[-1,1]\times [-1,1]}(\xi)d\xi \\
=\int_{[-1,1]\times [-1,1]}e^{2\pi i x \cdot \xi} d\xi \\
=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1e^{2\pi i x_1 \xi_1}e^{2\pi i x_2 \xi_2} d\xi_1 d\xi_2 \\
=\int_{-1}^1 e^{2\pi i x_2 \xi_2}d\xi_2\int_{-1}^1e^{2\pi i x_1 \xi_1} d\xi_1  \\
$$

Now $\int_{0}^1e^{2\pi i x_1 \xi_1} d\xi_1=\frac{e^{2\pi i x_1 \xi_1}}{2\pi i x_1}\big\vert_{-1}^1=\frac{e^{2\pi i x_1 }-e^{-2 \pi x_1}}{2\pi i x_1}=2\operatorname{sinc} (2\pi x_1)$

And $\int_{-1}^1e^{2\pi i x_2 \xi_2} d\xi_2=\frac{e^{2\pi i x_2 \xi_2}}{2\pi i x_2}\big\vert_{-1}^1=\frac{e^{2\pi i x_2 }-e^{-2\pi i x_2}}{2\pi i x_2}=2\operatorname{sinc} (2\pi x_2)$

Therefore, we have that $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(F) =\frac{e^{2\pi i x_1 }-e^{-2\pi i x_1 }}{2\pi i x_1}\frac{e^{2\pi i x_2 }-e^{-2\pi i x_2 }}{2\pi i x_2}=4\operatorname{sinc} (2\pi x_1)\operatorname{sinc} (2\pi x_2)$$

Have I computed this result properly?

Comment: Decompose the integrand into the product $e^{2\pi ix_1\xi_1} e^{2\pi ix_2\xi_2}$ and calculate iterated integral $d\xi_1\,d\xi_2.$

Comment: In the now deleted question, you gave a formula. It was not quite right but you are getting close. Don't be confused by that $x\cdot \xi$, here $x$ and $\xi$ are vectors.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think I have something in the result. Should this end up resembling sinx/x since the inverse fourier transform of sinx/x is a rectangle?